# Omnet/Inet : how to access class/submodules to get variables values

Tags: omnet++, inet

in my simulation there is a mobile node composed by the following components from the inet framework:

[image]

Now I am working on the `UdpApp` which is `UDPVideoStreamCli.cc` which is also given by inet framework as one of example udp application.

Now as you can see from the image I had to access to the lisp module (which is an instance of `LispRouting.cc`) because I have to read some values or call some public methods of that class...**how can I do that**? All I know is that I have to start from

```
getParentModule()->getSubmodule();
```

but then I don't know how to go on...can you help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(LispRouting *)getParentModule()->getSubmodule("lisp")
```

will do the trick. Be sure to check if the returned pointer is not null.

Generally this is bad design as it hard-codes the name and the relative position of the LispRouting module. Any change in naming/architecture will cause crashes.

A proper design would be to create a parameter that specifies the name/path of the lisp submodule (with default value) and then use

```
#include "inet/common/ModuleAccess.h"
...
LispRouting *lr = getModuleFromPar<LispRouting>(par("lispModule"), this);
```

and then add a parameter to the module's NED file:

```
string lispModule = default("^.lisp");
```

meaning the default place where you can find the lisp module is: go one level up and then find the submodule named "lisp". This is a much better pattern, because the user can later reconfigure the name/placement of the lisp module without breaking the code.